# Chrome extension - where to put more code

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm refactoring js plugin for chrome.
Its mostly based on jQuery with q and handlebars libraries.

For now there is 30k lines of code (2k in background page).
Is it better to include more logic in background or in content-scripts?

If for example I move most of functions to background page, and call them through chrome.runtime.sendMessage with callbacks.

Currently there are about 5k messages send between bg and content-scripts in one plugin run and it takes about 2 min.

Will moving help performance or will it crash it?

Comment: Moving code to BG and using messages to call the functions is a bad idea, it will only slow down your content scripts. You should ask yourself why there are so many messages between BG and content scripts in your extensions and try to reduce them to the bare minimum. Note that all chrome APIs are present and usable inside content scripts, so there's no need to use messages for those. Also try to reduce the scope of your content scripts, are they executed only when and where they are needed? If not, that is a performance problem with such big scripts.

Comment: Correction, [only 3 chrome APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are available for a content script.

Comment: OK, thank you, Now i know how to start.